# Do all points of a $C^1$ boundary fulfill the Poincaré cone condition?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Do all points of a $C^1$ boundary fulfill the Poincaré cone condition?

PCC: Suppose $D \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is an open domain. A point $x_0 \in \partial D$ fulfills the PCC if we can touch it with the vertex of a truncated cone $V$ such that $V \subset D^c$.